React - redux, can i split reducer action to features if i have one object in state?
I have an object of Items in Redux store, each Item has its own items Array. So, Item and subItem have functions: create, delete its self. And in reducer of the store i have functions: createItem, deleteItem, createItemOfItem, deleteItemOfItem.. can i split this logic to slicers or another method to do it? Can i do this in Vanilla React with useReducer? Tried all my best with useReducer and Redux toolkit
The example of useReducer Code
 const eachObjectOfArray = {  id: number;
    type: string;
    question: string;
    answers: { id: number; text: string }[];
    targetAnswersId: number[];
  } //The example of each object in state array

 const reducer = (state, action) => { //state is array of eachObjectOfArray objects 

  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_CARD": {
      const id = Math.floor(Date.now()).toString();
      const newCard = {
        id,
        type: "oneAnswer",
        question: "",
        answers: [],
        targetAnswersId: [],
      };
      return [...state, newCard];
    }

    case "DELETE_CARD": {
      if (!action.payload) {
        throw new Error("Action DELETE_CARD needs an payload field");
      }

      const sorted = state.filter((item) => item.id != action.payload);
      return sorted;
    }
    case "SET_CARD_QUESTION": {
      const tempCards = state.map((card) => {
        if (card.id == action.payload.id) {
          return { ...card, question: action.payload.text };
        } else {
          return card;
        }
      });
      return tempCards;
    }

    case "SET_CARD_TYPE": {
      const tempCards = state.map((card) => {
        if (card.id == action.payload.id) {
          return { ...card, type: action.payload.type };
        } else {
          return card;
        }
      });
      return tempCards;
    }

    case "CREATE_CARD_ANSWER": {
      const id = Math.floor(Date.now()).toString();

      const tempCards = state.map((card) => {
        if (card.id == action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...card,
            answers: [...card.answers, { id, text: action.payload.text }],
          };
        } else {
          return card;
        }
      });
      return tempCards;
    }
    case "DELETE_CARD_ANSWER": {
      const tempCards = state.map((card) => {
        if (card.id == action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...card,
            answers: card.answers.filter(
              (answer) => answer.id != action.payload.answerId
            ),
          };
        } else {
          return card;
        }
      });
      return tempCards;
    }

    case "ADD_TARGET_ANSWER_ID": {
      const tempCards = state.map((card) => {
        if (card.id == action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...card,
            targetAnswersId: [...card.targetAnswersId, action.payload.answerId],
          };
        } else {
          return card;
        }
      });
      return tempCards;
    }

    case "DELETE_TARGET_ANSWER_ID": {
      const tempCards = state.map((card) => {
        if (card.id == action.payload.id) {
          return {
            ...card,
            targetAnswersId: card.targetAnswersId.filter(
              (targetAnswerId) => targetAnswerId != action.payload.answerId
            ),
          };
        } else {
          return card;
        }
      });
      return tempCards;
    }

    default:
      throw new Error("Cannot find action with type: " + action.type);
  }
};

export default reducer;

The answers array is that ItemOfItem like i methioned before

Can you [edit] to clarify what you mean exactly by "can I split reducer action to features if I have one object in state"? Please also include a [mcve] of the relevant code you are trying to work with so we can see what you are trying to do. Include details about what isn't working as expected and what you are trying to accomplish.

@DrewReese Edited, can i split logic? It's too more code because i have functions to edit arrays in array, what to do if i have mor deep objects which need to update?

What are you trying to split though? Are you asking if you can abstract each reducer case into a utility function that computes the next state? Something like case ADD_CARD: return addCard(state, action);? Or something else? It's not clear what your question is about and what you expect an answer to be.

@DrewReese I just want to say that it's a big problem when i have A BIG OBJECT, that means in this BIG OBJECT i have Object which has an Object..  And all this  objects have functions to update state in one file.  And it's become trash code when i call  like: createObject, createObjectOfObject, createObjectOfObjectOfObject..
